# Why does Laravel take so long to load?

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-ec2

We have a Laravel Application that takes more than 5 seconds to load any blade view. However, this just happens in our production server (apache) that is hosted in a EC2 instance, locally the app loads pretty fast.

Even we tried to `return 0` instead of a view, and it also takes 2 or 3 seconds just to show 0, without calling any API, database or nothing, just the controller that is activated through the route.

Any hint why this could be happening?

Route

```
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index' )
->name('home');
```

HomeController

```
public function index(){
     return 0;
}
```

This simple process to `return 0` normally takes more than 2 seconds.

Is this a normal behavior or a Laravel App or maybe an apache configuration or internal laravel middlewares is causing this slowness?

Comment: For our site on our dev servers it loads in about 300ms. You probably have a problem with apache or your server config.

Comment: Properly configured servers and applications will not take more than a couple milliseconds to respond (without transfer times and if no database is accessed).

Answer (score 0):

It's not Php/Laravel problem. Something wrong with your server.

I would recommend reinstall Apache/NGINx